# 'open in terminal' option is enabled on the right-click menu, but it goes directory to the home directory

Tags: terminal

When I am in a folder and I want to open that folder on the terminal, the 'open in terminal' option on the right-click menu takes me to my home directory. I have two computers, both of them have Ubuntu 18.04, This problem exists on only one of them. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem and fixed it. On the terminal preferences, I had assigned a custom command to be run instead of my shell. I unchecked the option to run a custom command and things went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever ran the following cmd to specify the path when terminal opens.

```
echo "cd some_path" >> ~/.bashrc
```

The problem is with the bashrc file just search for the bashrc file and remove the " cd some_path " line from the file and save it.
The problem should be solved.
Cheers.